# How can I reduce computational time in a OPL script using CPLEX?

Tags: performance, cplex, opl

I'm an engineering student, new user of CPLEX and OPL. I modelled an electric vehicle scheduling problem, using OPL in CPLEX.

It takes around 20min to give me an optimal solution for an instance of 4 service trips, 2 depots and 2 charging stations.

I'm currently trying to run a real example of 100 service trips, 1 depot and 1 charging station, but is taking me forever to get an answer (it is running for the last 17h).

Any suggestions on how to speed up the process?

Answer (score 0):

You could set a time limit and then instead of an optimal solution you'll get a solution after the time limit. You could also try to see with the profiler where time is spent.

A few links to help you:

[Performance Tuning Using CPLEX Optimization Studio IDE](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039021&aid=1)

[MIP Tuning](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21400023)

[CPO Introduction](https://www.slideshare.net/PhilippeLaborie/an-introduction-to-cp-optimizer)

Comment: I will read those links and try it out. Thank you so much for your time!